# Animatint BlurEffect in a style works but animating DropShadowEffect causes error?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to animate a `DropShadowEffect` I have applied to one grid and a `BlurEffect` that I have applied to another grid.

The blur animation seems to work fine and this is the code.

```
<Style x:Key="BluredGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="extentions:GridExtention.IsBlured" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Radius" From="0" To="10" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).Radius" From="10" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

<Grid Background="{DynamicResource BrHostBackground}">
    <Grid extentions:GridExtention.IsBlured="{Binding BackgroundIsBlured}" Style="{StaticResource BluredGridStyle}">
        <Grid.Effect>
            <BlurEffect x:Name="BlurEffect" Radius="0"/>
        </Grid.Effect>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

But when I try with the drop shadow I get errors. Here is my initial code.

```
        <Style x:Key="DropShaodowGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).BlurRadius" From="0" To="80" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Effect).BlurRadius" From="80" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    <Grid Visibility="{Binding HardwareLoadingVisibility}">
        <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" Width="550" Height="250" Style="{DynamicResource DropShaodowGridStyle}">
            <Grid.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Opacity="0.8"/>                    
            </Grid.Effect>               
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

This generates the following error

`InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve all property references in the property path '(Effect).BlurRadius'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.`

If I change the property to `(Effect).Radius` I get the same error.

I also tried changing the property to `(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)` which generated this error

`InvalidOperationException: 'Effect' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)'.`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the answer.

I had to assign a default value to the property in the style.

```
<Style x:Key="DropShaodowBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="0"></DropShadowEffect>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).BlurRadius" From="0" To="80" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).BlurRadius" From="80" To="0" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```